# How to use a variable from one stored procedure in a different stored procedure (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a stored procedure as follows (this is a simplified version - the SP does a lot of other things but these are the key parts):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_uspCustomSP]

AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #custno(custno int) 
INSERT INTO #custno
EXEC    usp_GetCustomerNo


DECLARE @custnumber nvarchar(5)  
SET @custnumber = (SELECT custno FROM #custno)  

DROP TABLE #custno-- drop table so fresh each time

END
```

This SP works as I want it to.  However, I want to be able to refer to the value of @custnumber in a different stored procedure.  Is there any way of persisting the value of @custnumber but without rerunning usp_GetCustomerNo (as every time it is run, the value of @custnumber changes - I want to be able to use the exact number as stored in the variable.)

EDIT: I've had a really helpful response below suggesting I include an output parameters.  I have thought about this but I'm not sure how to refer to this output elsewhere (in a different SP) without re-running the entire SP at the same time.

Apologies if I've not included enough information.

Many thanks,
Helen

Comment: Perhaps these SPs need _input arguments_ (like `@cust_id`) and _output variables_ (like `@cust_no out`).

Comment: There are no **global variables** in SQL SERVER. To obtain any value you must: 1) get it from elsewhere as input argument 2) select it from table 3) get it as an output from another sp or function or whatever.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  I think the best thing I can do is store the value in a table as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the stored procedure return the value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_uspCustomSP] (
    @custnumber nvarchar(5) OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #custno(custno int) ;

    INSERT INTO #custno (custno)        
        EXEC usp_GetCustomerNo;

    SELECT  @custnumber = custno FROM #custno ; 

    DROP TABLE #custno-- drop table so fresh each time
END;
```

Having said that, I have some comments on the stored procedure:

- There is no need to drop the temporary table.  I prefer table variables, because it is obvious they go out of scope.
- I think it is dangerous to return a single value in a table.  Why not use a scalar function or `OUTPUT` parameter for `usp_GetCustomerNo`?
- You should get in the habit of putting semicolons at the end of statements and always using a column list with `INSERT`.

You would call the stored procedure as:

declare @custnumber nvarchar(5);

```
exec sp_executesql _uspCustomSP,
                   N'@custnumber nvarchar(5) output',
                   @custnumber=@custnumber output;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks very much for this.  If I call the stored procedure from elsewhere, what syntax would I use to refer to this specific output (i.e. without re-executing the SP?) i.e. I want to have a different stored procedure which selects just this value.

Comment: Thanks again for your edit above! V helpful suggestions re. my code.  regarding calling the stored procedure - does this not re-execute the stored procedure? For various reasons the value changes every time the SP is executed so I don't want the value to get changed as a result of re-executing it.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @HelenS so may be you need to specify which row you need here `SELECT  @custnumber = custno FROM #custno ; ` What if `#custno` table contains many rows? Which one is the right for `@custnumber` scalar variable?

Comment: Hi Ivan.  #custno will only ever contain one value because the called SP only ever returns one value.  Cheers,Helen

Comment: @HelenS Let's check this. Turn that line `SELECT  @custnumber = custno FROM #custno ; ` into this: `SET @custnumber = (SELECT  custno FROM #custno)`

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it :) I am still confused though about how to get the value of the variable without re-executing the SP (which would change the value, as it changes every time it's run.)

Comment: I believe that is because `usp_GetCustomerNo` has similar issues in it. Like a lack of input arguments. Update your question with more details please @HelenS.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Unfortunately though I can't amend usp_GetCustomerNo as it is an existing SP which I don't have permission to edit.  I'll ask around within my team and see if anybody can help here.  Thanks again.